# Deserializing GSON with generics and inheiritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, gson

I have the following class:

```
public class AdminCommand<O extends AdminCommandType, P>  {
  O type;
  P payload;

  public AdminCommand() {

  }

  public AdminCommand(O type, P payload) {
    this.type = type;
    this.payload = payload;
  }
}
```

I am able to serialize and deserialize it properly.

However, I need to make child classes, so I do the following:

```
public class AdminCommand<O extends AdminCommandType, P>  {
  O type;
  P payload;

  public AdminCommand() {

  }

  public AdminCommand(O type, P payload) {
    this.type = type;
    this.payload = payload;
  }
}

public interface AdminCommandType {}
```

I have taken the enum in the first class and converted it to an interface.

I am running into problems when I deserialize this class.  I tried to use a type token with the following definition:

```
new TypeToken<TestCommand<<Enum which implements the interface>, <Regular POJO>>(){}.getType();
```

However, when I try to deserialize, I get 2 different errors:

1. The Enum gets cast to a String
2. The POJO deserializes into a TreeMap

Is there a way to I can deserialize this class?

Comment: Could you please include your complete code in which you call Gson methods? E.g. which exact Gson methods you call, how exactly you create the `TypeToken`, ...

Comment: I talked to my team about the object model.  We went another direction.  We can now serialize an inheirited, non generic POJO.